# How can I implement Basic Authentication with JWT authentication in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, basic-authentication

I have built a `Spring-Boot` application that works with `jwt` authentication.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.diplie</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RC1</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <springfox-version>2.2.2</springfox-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger 2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>repository.springsource.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I want have a basic authentication, when I use `Swagger` I want to have a popup with when I click on the `Try Out` button

***For example:***

[image]

how can use two security(form base,JWT token) filters of spring security on same endpoint?

***WebSecurityConfig***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling().and().anonymous().and().servletApi().and().authorizeRequests()

                // Allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**").permitAll().antMatchers("/swagger-resources/**")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/v2/api-docs").permitAll().antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("**/*.html").permitAll().antMatchers("**/*.css").permitAll().antMatchers("**/*.js")
                .permitAll()

                // Allow anonymous logins
                .antMatchers("/user/User").permitAll().antMatchers("/locality/**").hasAuthority("Admin")
                .antMatchers("/category/**").hasAuthority("Admin").antMatchers("/item").hasAuthority("Item")
                .antMatchers("/item/userItems").hasAuthority("Item").antMatchers("item/lookFor").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("item/items").hasAuthority("User")

                // All other request need to be authenticated
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in
                // header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        // Créer un compte par défaut
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
    }
}
```

***TokenAuthenticationService***

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService {

    static ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");

    static void addAuthentication(HttpServletResponse res, String username) {

        String JWT = Jwts.builder().setSubject(username)
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + getExpirationTime()))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, getSecret()).compact();
        res.addHeader(getHeaderString(), getTokenPrefix() + " " + JWT);
    }

    static Authentication getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(getHeaderString());
        if (token != null) {
            // Analyse du jeton.
            String user = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(getSecret()).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(getTokenPrefix(), ""))
                    .getBody().getSubject();
            return user != null ? new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, emptyList()) : null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the secret
     */
    public static String getSecret() {
        return bundle.getString("secret");
    }

    /**
     * @return the expirationTime
     */
    public static long getExpirationTime() {
        return Long.valueOf(bundle.getString("expiration.time"));
    }

    /**
     * @return the tokenPrefix
     */
    public static String getTokenPrefix() {
        return bundle.getString("token.prefix");
    }

    /**
     * @return the headerString
     */
    public static String getHeaderString() {
        return bundle.getString("header.string");
    }

}
```

***JWTLoginFilter***

```
public class JWTLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    public JWTLoginFilter(String url, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(url));
        setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        AccountCredentials creds = new ObjectMapper().readValue(req.getInputStream(), AccountCredentials.class);
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(creds.getUsername(),
                creds.getPassword(), Collections.emptyList()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        TokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(res, auth.getName());
    }
}
```

***JWTAuthenticationFilter***

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = TokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) request);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

***AccountCredentials***

```
public class AccountCredentials {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public AccountCredentials() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @return the username
     */
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * @param username
     *            the username to set
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * @param password
     *            the password to set
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your current authentication scheme? Where do you store your user information?

Comment: @MarcTarin Acctually i don't store anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to create two different `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configurations with different root URLs. If the URLs overlap (ie `/admin and /**`) then you will need to define priority by using `@Order` annotation on the configuration.

Here's a working example for HTTP Basic and Form based authentication.

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/TestMultipleLoginPagesFormAndBasic.git

```
package com.test;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestMultipleLoginPagesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestMultipleLoginPagesApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Controller
class MvcController {
    @RequestMapping(path="form/formLogin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formLoginPage() {
        return "formLogin";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="form/formHome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formHomePage() {
        return "formHome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="basic/basicHome", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userHomePage() {
        return "basicHome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path="basic/logout", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userLogout(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        return "basicLogout";
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(1)
class FormSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/form/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("FORM_USER")
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/form/formLogin").permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/form/formLoginPost").permitAll()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/form/formHome")
            .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/form/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/form/formLogin")
            .and()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user")
            .password("test")
            .roles("FORM_USER");
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
class BasicAuthSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/basic/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("BASIC_USER")
            .antMatchers("/basic/logout").permitAll()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("basic_user")
            .password("test")
            .roles("BASIC_USER");
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(3)
class RootUrlSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
         * Put any security expectations from the root URL here, currently everything is permitted.
         * Since it's the last in the order /form/** and /basic/** have a priority over it.
         */
        http.antMatcher("/**")
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

**Note:** Since these login pages are not from different applications, they share the SecurityContextHolder or the security context. So if you login from one login page and then try to go the protected resource of the other, you won't be redirected to the next login page. Instead you'll get the 403 (depending on the roles assigned by the different login pages). At a time only one login session can be maintained.